# ros code generator c++

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have not been able to find things with this. What I would like to write (or to use, if already existing) would be a tool like
catkin_create_pkg, but where

1. you can specify the number of subscribers and publishers (and or client / server)
2. the corresponding message types
3. where the tool would also set up the skeleton for both unit testing and integration testing
4. where the tool would create all of this in a nice OO fashion.

Is there anything like this? If not, does anyone have any recommendations of how to do this?
Thanks, please criticize away!
Adrian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319917/ros-code-generator-c++/) by [arta](https://answers.ros.org/users/37857/arta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could take a look at the [ROS package generator](http://rosin-project.eu/tool/ros-package-generator) created by Tecnalia as part of the [ROSIN project](http://rosin-project.eu/).

Based on something it calls an *interface specification* and a set of templates, it generates what I believe would cover your bullets.

From the readme:

> The following packages are about the automatic creation of ROS packages (so far c++ and python).
>
> To do so the input needed are:
>
> - A package template: a template is created by a template Designer. It contains the list of files to be automatically generated. The Developer just has to select the template that best fits his needs.
> - An interface specification: a xml file describing mainly the interface of the package to create, according to the template. This file is to be filled by the Developer, using the interface proposed by the template, according to the concrete needs of the package he is willing to create

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arta](https://answers.ros.org/users/37857/arta/) on 2019-04-01**:
Thanks for the prompt reply, I will look into it!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-01**:
No problem.

I'd encourage you to provide feedback to the developers. I'm sure they'd welcome your input.